# Components not rendered dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render dynamically components in my component that looks like this:

```
const renderPeriod = (code, fieldId) => {
  switch (code) {
    case 'work' || 'vacation':
      return <WorkOrVacation fieldId={fieldId} />;
    case 'sickness:
      return <Sickness fieldId={fieldId} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export const PeriodeContent= ({
  fieldId,
  confirmed,
  employer,
  code,
}) => (
  <div className={styles.period}>
    {confirmed=== false &&
      <div>
        <Element>{employer}</Element>
        <VerticalSpacer space={2} />
        {renderPeriod(code, fieldId)}
      </div>
    }
  </div>
);
```

On inspecting the code in the console, I can see that I am getting in to the function renderPeriod, but nothing gets rendered. I have tried with hard-coding and just returning the string like this:

```
switch (code) {
    case 'work' || 'vacation':
      return 'test' // <WorkOrVacation fieldId={fieldId} />;
```

And that didn't work either. I have double checked if I am sending the right code, and I was sending the work code, so I have no idea what is wrong with this code, and why is nothing rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `||` in case statements, as `'work' || 'vacation'` simply evaluates to `'work'`. Using multiple cases will allow you to do what you want:

```
..
switch (code) {
  case 'work':
  case 'vacation':
    return <WorkOrVacation fieldId={fieldId} />;
  case 'sickness:
..
```